# Scala: how to generalize behaviour around unrelated Java classes

Tags: java, scala

I have two Java classes `Foo` and `Bar` (from a third part library which I am not supposed to change) and they are not related by any `interface`, `abstract` or any other classes.

However they have signature methods like

`public String createToken(String id)`

that is the same in both classes, and another method which is quite similar apart from the object type returned in the list:

for the class `Foo` => `public List[FooItem] getItems(String id)`

and for the class `Bar` => `public List[BarItem] getItems(String id)`

In my Scala code I am using these two classes in methods that are basically duplicated. For example:

```
def getFooItems(foo: Foo, id: String): Vector[FooItem] = {
  foo.createToken(id)
  foo.getItems(id).asScala.toVector
}

def getBarItems(bar:Bar, id: String): Vector[BarItem] = {
  bar.createToken(id)
  bar.getItems(id).asScala.toVector
}
```

As you can see the code is pretty much the same but for a lots of methods (and more than just two classes) it becomes quite a sort of huge duplicated code.

Is there any way with Scala to generalise the code to get a sort of:

```
def getItems[A,B](someClass:A, id: String): Vector[B] = {
  someClass.createToken(id)
  someClass.getItems(id).asScala.toVector
}
```

Or the duck typing the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try out [typeclass pattern](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html).

First you have to define interface common for `Foo` and `Bar`:

```scala
trait Tokenable[T, TItem] {
   def createToken(t: T, id: String): String
   def getItems(t: T, id: String): List[TItem]
}
```

Then you need to define implementation for every class you want to apply it to:

```scala
object FooBar {
  class Foo {
    def createToken(id: String): String = ???
    def getItems(id: String): List[FooItem] = ???
  }
  class Bar {
    def createToken(id: String): String = ???
    def getItems(id: String): List[BarItem] = ???
  }

  class FooItem
  class BarItem

  implicit object FooTokenable extends Tokenable[Foo, FooItem] {
    def createToken(f: Foo, id: String) = f.createToken(id)
    def getItems(f: Foo, id: String) = f.getItems(id)
  }

  implicit object BarTokenable extends Tokenable[Bar, BarItem] {
    def createToken(b: Bar, id: String) = b.createToken(id)
    def getItems(b: Bar, id: String) = b.getItems(id)
  }
}
```

Now you can use it in any method with implicit `Tokenable` parameter:

```scala
import FooBar._

def getItemsAsVector[T, TItem](t: T, id: String)
    (implicit tok: Tokenable[T, TItem]) = {
  tok.createToken(t, id)
  tok.getItems(t, id).toVector
}

val vector = getItemsAsVector(new Foo, "my_id")
```

Comment: interesting suggestion, but I don't see a concrete vantage. I mean, you can in this way with an extra indirection having a facade but still you have to "repeat" all the methods per class, which is sort of pain when you have lots of classes and methods.

Comment: Yes, but you do it only once for each class like `Foo` or `Bar`, then you don't need to repeat yourself for every method that uses `Tokenable` like `getItemsAsVector`. I don't think it can be done with any less work, since you need to point to concrete method in every type anyway.

Answer (score 0):

how about this, use trait and class only

```
trait TokenManager {
  def createToken(id: String): String
}

class FooToken extends TokenManager {
  override def createToken(id: String) = Foo.createToken(id)
}


class BarToken extends TokenManager {
  override def createToken(id: String) = Bar.createToken(id)
}

def getToken(tokenManager: TokenManager, id: String): String = tokenManager.createToken(id)
```